# Clarification for return types in a function

Tags: swift

A have a few basic questions in regards to the returns a function has. Take for example the following function:

```
func add2(_ num1: Int, _ num2: Int) {
   print(num1 + num2)
}
```

**Questions:**

1.) There is no need for the word return before the print statement because it is just one return correct?

2.) What kind of return type would this be considered if it is just a print statement.

Comment: The return type is Void and you don’t need a return for that since it’s not a value

Comment: Meaning there is no specified return type, which means it can be anything correct?

Comment: No it can’t be anything it can only be nothing, that is the type Void. The function could also be written as `func add2(_ num1: Int, _ num2: Int) -> Void { return print(num1 + num2) }`

Answer (score 0):

Void is a [typealias](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/void) for the empty tuple, i.e. no values. There is only 1 way for a tuple to be empty tuple so void values are all the same, and so hold no information.

This concept is more generally called [Unit Type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type)

You can write `return` as the last statement in a void function but there’s no need to, because the return value is implied. You can return any expression that is itself void (return print(“…”)) but that’s not common.

You can write `-> Void` or even  `-> ()` as the function’s return type but this is implicit too if omitted.

Comment: What is an example of a common void function return value that is not `return print(“…”)`

Comment: Loads of functions are void functions, UserDefaults's set(_:forKey:), shuffle() on Array, mutating func's like toggle() on Bool, AVSpeechSynthesizer's speak(_:), any Void functions you define yourself.  They usually mutate the world via side effects one way or another, appending to a log file, closing a database, deleting a file.

Comment: I meant it’s not common, in the body of a void function, to write an expression like “return f()” where f is a void function. People generally write f() then return or just f(). The “return f()” means: compute f() and return that value, but as you wouldn’t normally write “return ()” to mean return void, writing return f() is not a popular style